# Why is my method not continuing after calling InflateObject.inflate(byte[] array)?

Tags: java, compression, inflate

I tried to create a program that has to decomprimise the content of a file.

My code is the following, the problem is that after I called the `decompresser.inflate(result)` nothing is executed anymore in this method. Do I have to replace result through another field or where is the error?

```
//The string with the not yet decompressed content is converted into a byte array Content was earlier defined and initialised
byte[] notDeComPresCo = new byte[content.length()];
for (int i = 0; i < content.length(); i++) {
    notDeComPresCo[i] = content.substring(i, i + 1).getBytes()[0];
}
//Until here the programm works as I want, then the problem starts:

//A new inflater is contructed to decompress the byte array into an decompressed byte array
Inflater decompressor = new Inflater();
decompressor.setInput(notDeComPresCo, 0, notDeComPresCo.length);
byte[] result = new byte[content.length()];
try {
    System.out.println("This is printed");
    int decompressedDataLength = decompressor.inflate(result);
    System.out.println("This system.out.println - command is not printed"); 
    decompressor.end();
    String x = new String(result, 0, decompressedDataLength, "UTF-8");
} catch (DataFormatException e) {
    throw new InvalidGitObjectFileException("The content could not be decompressed.");
}
```

No error is outgiven in the console, the method just ends before `System.out.println("This system.out.println - command is not printed")` is reached.

Comment: how long did you wait? is the `InvalidGitObjectFileException` thrown?

Comment: Yes, it is, sry, i missed that ... but it is thrown in the other method that calls this method!

Comment: Decompressor should decompress, and Inflator should inflate...... but thats off the topic

Answer (score 0):

I have 2 guesses:

1. `int decompressedDataLength = decompressor.inflate(result);` is throwing some kind of runtime exception that is swallowed by upper layer and thats why you don't see any reasonable output
2. length of `notDeComPresCo` is 0

Aaand my bet is on 1. Add extra `catch` clause like

```
catch (Exception e) {System.out.println(e.getMessage());}
```

and check if there is no exception thrown.

Comment: Well, notDeComPresCo has a length of 85 and this Exception is also not thrown ... does that mean the problem is a kind of runtime exception?

Comment: `catch (Exception e)` woud catch `RuntimeException` as well

Comment: What is happening when you are debugging this code?

Comment: Btw, you can also do `e.printStacktrace();`, or `e.fillInStackTrace(System.out);`

Comment: The decompressor is filling the buffer array